# How to reset wordpress but not plugins and settings

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

How to mass delete all posts with tags & comments but not plugins. There are some plugins but, Is there any plugin available which deletes all data related to posts like tags, comments etc.?

Is it possible in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to delete posts, categories, tags, photos, media, EVERYTHING.  just clear the database entirely.  Plugins will recreate their db entries if they need them.

Go into phpmyadmin and find the right database, then in content, select all of the tables and drop them.  You don't want to delete the actual table though.

Now next time you go to your site, You'll start over fresh at the wordpress install area.

WARNING.  IF YOU HAVE A CUSTOM THEME.
THis will delete your theme settings so you may want to back them up in the theme control panel before doing this.
This will not delete the actual media in your install, so you'll still have pictures in your wp-content/uploads folder.

IF YOU DON"T want to do that, you can always try this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/

Comment: @blackfire  Did this work for you?  Can you close the question by marking it answered?